# Is it generally safe to allow clients to have access to their Stripe Subscription ID's to simplify database operations?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I'm building a centralized Stripe Endpoint to manage user stripe-related data like subscriptions, paymentMethods, etc. Using Elements client side, and a custom mongodb endpoint.

When fleshing out the endpoint, my schema for containing subscriptions is within an array.

```
...
 subscriptions:[{
        subscriptionID:{
            type: String
        },
        subscriptionUUID:{
            type: String // unused
        }
        platform:{
            type: String
        },
        status:{
            type: Boolean
        },
        details:{
            type: String
        },
        debutInvoice:{
            type: String
        }

    }],
...
```

This leaves me with the question of how I should proceed to letting users manage their subscriptions? Should I give them access to their subscriptionID? Is that safe?

Edit: Stripe support have confirmed that exposing ID's like si_xxxxx and sub_xxxxx are safe, as they are tied to the customer account which is then in turn tied to your private key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: *It depends*.

As long as you don't expose by any ways your Stripe keys, you may or might be fine.

Also, usually all you want if to have a unique identifier for each customer and have a way to relate that user ID with any other kind of third party services ID's and resources.

I don't know what your business logic is or how your database schema looks like, but I'd say for many conventional user-subscription relationships, all you want is to keep track of everything from user ID of any kinds.

Some workarounds would be:

- Encrypt Stripe ID's with secret keys,

or -like I mention at my second paragraph-:

- to have a middleware service doing the 1:1 relationship - fetch of the corresponding Stripe subscription resource.

Now that after some talks & edits it looks like this is an schema related thing. I'd say that if you have a `User` collection with a `subscriptions` array property. Then it'd simplify things.

So:

```
const UserSchema = {
  name: String,
  email: String,
  stripeCustomerId: String,
  stripeSubscriptions: [String]
}
```

Then you can [query an array for an element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/) in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply!
  
Basically I use locally stored email addresses to do the 1:1 relationship on Stripe, with a subscription object array to retrieve the ID, and the item id.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure if hashing would do anything here. That would still require a Stripe ID lookup to be hashed and checked for equality.

Comment: I just saw your edit, this seems to become a MongoDB question ... Explain why you have an Array

Comment: Basically I'm using a centralized stripe endpoint for my platform, that allows branching platforms to store their particular users payment data centrally. 

In the schema for the user, is a subscriptions array that I keep a local copy of, which is auto checked against stripe per user. The issue is when I come to wanting to delete a particular subscription from a user within an Array. I'm unsure what to identify by? So hence, I'm asking if giving the end user access to their subscription array (which contains, the ID and the item ID) to be able to select which from the array to remove

Comment: Share the user document schema. It may not need to be an array

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DisCNMN4

The 'charges' aspect is purely a placeholder for now, and is not currently used.

Comment: Update your question, it's better to have a great formatted question

Comment: Updated, sorry for the rushed question!

Comment: Saw your latest update, and that's actually a lot better of a schema design, many thanks for that. I guess the solution to remain the safest would to be have a 1:1 matching service for subscriptionID's issued by stripe, to my own issued subscriptions UUID? I think that would be a good idea, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yes, that's actually prob a "safest practice idea"

Comment: @diegoaguilar Followed up with this through stripe support, they say that you can safely expose these ID's to the customer. Just wanted to pass this info along for your knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it's generally fine to expose ID's as long as you don't expose API secrets.